# navigation menu hidden behind div in ie7, but works in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

http://tinyurl.com/d48sf22
In the above link navigation menu is hidden behind div, tried the position relative property and zindex as well tc. to make menu show on top of div, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Try going back through the DOM tree and making sure the navigation's containers have position: relative and a high enough z-index on them. IE7 does z-indexing a little differently; instead of being relative to the document as a whole, z-indexing only applies inside its containing element.

In other words:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav">Blah</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Blah</p>
</div>
```

Giving the nav a z-index will only affect other elements inside the header. It will still go underneath the content as the content div appears later down the document, which gives it a higher 'natural' z-index than the header.

However, if you give the header a higher z-index than the content div, that should cause the navigation to appear over the top of the content.

Make sure you have either position: relative or position: absolute when you declare a z-index as it won't work otherwise. I've noticed a couple of elements on your page that have z-index but no positioning.